# How to remove whitener from bench?

Tags: metals, stain

I accidentally wrote something from whitener / white correction fluid on a metal bench.  I want to remove it.. Any possible ways ?

Comment: A picture would help; right now i'm not seeing why it wouldn't just scratch off with a fingernail after it dries - correction fluid doesn't adhere very well to nonporus/shiny surfaces

Comment: Hi Nityoday, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience. It's a good idea to review the information in the [tour] and [help] in the menubar at the top of the page.

Comment: @Stan pretty sure OP meant to put [tag:cleaning] tag and misclicked.

Comment: @Stan I guess people who have knowledge about clothing might know this too ..

Comment: I submitted an edit to the tag, it just needs peer review. LHSE might not have enough peers though!

Comment: Tags have been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bench is *unpainted* metal, you can simply scrape the dried correction fluid off with a knife or other blade. Be gentle so you don't scratch the metal surface too.

Answer (score 0):

Rubbing alcohol or nail paint remover might work.

Comment: Hi aashii, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience. It's a good idea to review the information in the [tour] and [help] in the menubar at the top of the page.

Comment: @Stan that canned comment doesn't mean a lot to the author of this post. The answer is short and to the point. What exactly is missing or wrong with it? Instead of pointing people at long pages please let them know what's wrong.

Comment: Alright I'll try this and let you know..

Comment: "*Might*" work?  We look for definitive answers here.  Can you provide some evidence that this will work?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wrong? Missing? What is your problem with welcoming and inviting someone to augment their information about this site? I think your inferences were wrong or missing something about my "canned" comment. I don't find your comment correct or helpful; but, thanks for your attempted guidance in this matter.

Comment: @Stan as a new user reading the first comment you posted it reads like "Thanks for posting, but it's bad, you need to read [links here and here] in order to use this site". Sorry, but this is not very welcoming. Again, my own personal view.

Comment: I used "might work" because i didn't clean the whitener from bench but from my glass table. I am not sure that it would work for the bench or not.